# Android VideoView LinearLayout LayoutParams

Tags: android, layout, parameters, android-linearlayout, android-videoview

My app plays a video using VideoView. I am using a LinearLayout to add some text, the video and then some buttons.

My question is what kind of layout params can I use for the VideoView to make sure it plays well in all phones? Basically, when in portrait mode, I want the complete width to be used, and video height to be used. When in landscape, I would like it to look more like the full screen mode.

I have noticed that this setting works well on myTouch for both portrait and landscape,

new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,480);

and, this works on Droid for both portrait and landscape,

new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is what kind of layout
>   params can I use for the VideoView to
>   make sure it plays well in all phones?

Have it fill all available space. `VideoView` will scale the video to take advantage of whatever room you give it.

Comment: When I have it FILL_PARENT, FILL_PARENT, on landscape mode, it does not scale to full screen. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chris: with only the information you have supplied, not really. Use `hierarchyviewer` to make sure you're getting your `LayoutParams` set properly. Consider using XML for your layouts instead of Java.

Comment: How much of the screen does it fill?  I think I had the same issue one time and it was related to it sizing and leaving space for the bottom nav bar or something.